# Generate compile_commands.json using cmake

Tags: c++

I am trying to generate a compile_commands.json for the google-cloud-cpp project using the cmake build. I tried this:

```
$ cmake -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -Hsuper -Bcmake-out
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.1.10010046
.....
.....
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    BUILD_TESTING

$ cmake --build cmake-out -- -j 4
.....
.....
[ 98%] Performing test step for 'google_cloud_cpp_project'
        Start   1: bucket_access_control_test
  1/143 Test   #1: bucket_access_control_test ................................   Passed    0.02 sec
.....
.....
100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 143

Total Test time (real) =  19.13 sec
[100%] Completed 'google_cloud_cpp_project'
[100%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_project
```

One thing is that BUILD_TESTING seems to be ignored - it produces a message while generating build files and all the tests run.  The more immediate thing for me is that no compile_commands.json is produced even though the flag is set. Both settings show up in cmake-out/CMakeCache.txt

```
$ grep -E 'BUILD_TESTING|COMPILE_C' cmake-out/CMakeCache.txt
BUILD_TESTING:UNINITIALIZED=OFF
CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=ON
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS
CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
```

Am I missing something? Should I be doing anything else? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the super build. The options you provided (`-DBUILD_TESTING=OFF` and `-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON`) are not passed down by the top-level `super/CMakeLists.txt` file.

You can try to install the dependencies to a directory in `$HOME` like so:

```
cmake -Hsuper -B.build/si -DGOOGLE_CLOUD_CPP_EXTERNAL_PREFIX=$HOME/local-cpp
cmake --build .build/si --target project-dependencies
```

and then configure and compile the code as usual:

```
cmake -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -H. -Bcmake-out -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$HOME/local-cpp
cmake --build cmake-out
```

Since you are using macOS, you may need to add `-DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/opt/libressl` or something similar.